# python - execute command and get output

Tags: python, cmd

I need to build a server that can execute a command line command and send back the output of the command

**Example:**

for the command- echo hello world, the server will return the string "hello world".

I tried to use `subprocess.call()` function but it returns a number and not a string. I have the sever ready, i just need this this.

**Code:**

```
type=struct.pack("B",2) #packing type
data=subprocess.call(client_data, shell=True)
length=struct.pack("H",len(data)) #packing lenght
client_soc.send(type+length+data)
```

Comment: please read [this tutorial on PMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using `subprocess.check_output` instead? From the manual:
"Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string."

It would be something like `data = subprocess.check_output(client_data, shell=True)` then.

See [this man page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this piece of code will help

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('ping google.com', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
print tmp
```